# How to find maximaum and minium value in array and also corresponding dates

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and i want some out put

```
Array
    (
[0] => Array
    (
        [DaySession1] => 
        [DaySession] => 
        [SubmitSessionDate] => 
        [id] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [DaySession2] => 
        [DaySession] => 
        [SubmitSessionDate] => 
        [id] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [DaySession3] => 2
        [DaySession] => 2
        [SubmitSessionDate] => 2014-09-03 23:58:56
        [id] => 2120
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [DaySession4] => 10
        [DaySession] => 10
        [SubmitSessionDate] => 2014-09-04 00:06:39
        [id] => 2121
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [DaySession5] => 
        [DaySession] => 
        [SubmitSessionDate] => 
        [id] => 
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [DaySession6] => 
        [DaySession] => 
        [SubmitSessionDate] => 
        [id] => 
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [DaySession7] => 6
        [DaySession] => 6
        [SubmitSessionDate] =>  2014-09-05 00:06:39
        [id] => 
    )
```

This is my coming array i want maximum  [DaySession] value from the above array and also want corresponding [SubmitSessionDate]

Same thing I also want minimum  [DaySession] value from the above array and corresponding [SubmitSessionDate] ?

Result should be:

```
Maximum Day session = 10 and SubmitSessionDate = 2014-09-04 00:06:39
Minimum Day Session =2  and SubmitSessionDate = 2014-09-03 23:58:56
```

Comment: If the array isn't extremely huge you can easily just loop through it. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just get the day sessions along with their keys, then ksort from there you can use `reset()` and `end()`. Example: [Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/mPuJvX)

```
$keys = array();
foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    if(!empty($val['DaySession'])) {
        $keys[$val['DaySession']] = $key;
    }
}

ksort($keys);
$min_key = reset($keys);
$max_key = end($keys);

echo "Maximum Day session = ".$array[$max_key]['DaySession']." and SubmitSessionDate = ".$array[$max_key]['SubmitSessionDate']." <br/>";
echo "Minimum Day session = ".$array[$min_key]['DaySession']." and SubmitSessionDate = ".$array[$min_key]['SubmitSessionDate'];
```

Comment: Thats work fine but issue is i have some blank array so i am facing issue and in your demo all arry have value thats why its working fine.How i can remove blank arrray

Comment: @Chauhan you can just filter them inside an if, check my revision